# iOS - Integrating MGTwitter without armv7s

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm using MGTwitterEngine in my apps and till iOS5, the app is working fine. I'm using twitter engine that as ".a" file.
But when compiling with latest XCode, its showing error that armv7s slice is not available.
 
I tried removing armv7s from the valid architectures and the problem solved. I'm able to build the app, run the app successfully on iPhone4, iPhone4S and also on iPhone5.
My questions is whether I'm following right way or not. Will Apple approve the apps that are not built with armv7s architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other go with it
Libraries are precompiled code. so they are built as per the architectures selected during compilation.
In latest iOS, its better to use Twitter/Social framework (as per iOS version)